# Adding Cordova Geofence plugin to project

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation

I'm currently experimenting with Cordova and the geolocation and [geofencing](https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence) plugins, I'm adding the geofence example code found on the website and try to either make it log some feedback in the console or notify the user with an alert, but it won't do anything at all.

The geolocation plugin example code works after building and installing the app on my Android phone.

Besides permissions in the manifest, editing the config files and the pasting the slightly edited example code in the index file, do I need to do anything else? I assume I'm installing it wrong.

//Edit:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Device Properties Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    window.geofence.initialize();
}

// onSuccess Geolocation
//
function onSuccess(position) {
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
                        'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                        'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                        'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                        'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                        'Timestamp: '          + position.timestamp                    + '<br />';
}

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

window.geofence.addOrUpdate({
    id:             "1",
    latitude:       45.6486100,
    longitude:      25.6061300,
    radius:         30000,
    transitionType: TransitionType.BOTH,
    notification: {
        id:             1,
        title:          "GeoTitle",
        text:           "GeoText.",
        openAppOnClick: true
    }
    }).then(function () {
        navigator.notification.alert(
        'Geofence successfully added',  // message
        alertDismissed,         // callback
        'Game Over',            // title
        'Done'                  // buttonName
        );
    }, function (reason) {
        navigator.notification.alert(
        'Adding geofence failed' + reason,  // message
        alertDismissed,         // callback
        'Game Over',            // title
        'Done'                  // buttonName
        );
    })

window.geofence.onTransitionReceived = function (geofences) {
    geofences.forEach(function (geo) {
        navigator.notification.alert(
    'Geofence transition detected' + geo,  // message
    alertDismissed,         // callback
    'Game Over',            // title
    'Done'                  // buttonName
    );
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Without any code or error we can only guess what's wrong, so could you please post some code?

Comment: That's right, thanks :) I've posted the whole index.html file, it contains the whole js code aswell, should I post the two config files and the AndroidManifest too?

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: None in the cordova console but if I check the console in Chrome I find two Uncaught TypeErrors, the first is Cannot read property addOrUpdate is undefined and the second is Promise is not a function. Also, if I try to get console feedback to adding the geofence, I get none.